# ArrowDB custom object "Count "API - does it use query parameters?

Tags: appcelerator, arrowdb

Created a model in an ArrowDB project and in the Arrow Builder web, can see the API Docs for the default APIs created for my model (Query, Create, Count, etc). The API doc for Count seem to indicate it has query parameters for where, sort, etc. but in testing directly from the API doc test and also in my code, the API always returns the *total* count of objects in the model, not a count based on filtered "where" criteria. Has anyone seem this behavior? Does the API in fact take these params and, if not, is there a good way to count the number of objects in a model based on a filtered criteria?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it creates a CustomObject in arrowDB?

http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/CustomObjects-method-count

Count does not seem to take any parameters so I guess 'where' does not work at the moment...

Comment: Thanks and yes, the documentation you referenced doesn't indicate any parameters are accepted. In Arrow Builder though, the auto-generated API docs (which include test calls) show that Count takes the same parameters as Query. Count without filtering is almost useless......at least for me. I will raise the discrepancy on the Appcelerator JIRA (and hope the fix is to add params to Count!)

Comment: I discovered that setting "count=true" on the Query API with return the total count of records that meet the Query criteria in the meta data, regardless of how many records you limit the query to return, so, absent the Count API accepting filtering clauses, this works too.